# (C++) Reading digits from text file

Tags: c++, file, digit

I have a text file which looks like this:

> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511

and etc. 20 lines in total.
What I want to do is to read every digit from the text file and put them into an array of integers(one element = one digit). How can I read only one digit from this text file, not the whole line?

Comment: use fgetc() to read char and convert to integer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>There are several ways to accomplish what you are looking for, in this post I'll describe three different methods. All three of them assume that you open your file using an `std::ifstream ifs ("filename.txt")` and that your "*array*" is actually a vector declared as `std::vector<int> v`.</sup>

<sup>At the end of this post there is also a little advice on how to speed up insertion into your vector.</sup>

---

#### I'd like to keep it simple..

The most simple approach is to read one `char` at a time using `operator>>` and then subtract `'0'` from the value returned.

The standard guarantee that `'0'` through `'9'` are sequential, and since a `char` is nothing but a numeric value printed in a different matter it can implicitly be casted to `int`.

```
char c;

while (ifs >> c)
  v.push_back (c - '0');
```

---

#### I love the STL, and hate writing loops..

This will by many be treated as the "*c++ way to do it*", espacially if you are talking to STL-fanboys, though it requires a lot more code to write..

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

...

std::transform (
  std::istream_iterator<char> (ifs),
  std::istream_iterator<char> (), 
  std::back_inserter (v),
  std::bind2nd (std::minus<int> (), '0')
);
```

---

#### I don't want to write loops, but why not use a lambda? [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

...

std::transform (
  std::istream_iterator<char> (iss),
  std::istream_iterator<char> (),
  std::back_inserter (v),
  [](char c){return c - '0';}
);
```

---

#### Will my `std::vector` reallocate storage upon each insertion?

Yes, probably. To speed things up you can reserve storage in your vector before you start doing any insertions, as in the below.

```
ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::end); // seek to the end of your file
v.reserve (ifs.tellg ()    ); // ifs.tellg () -> number of bytes in it
ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::beg); // seek back to the beginning
```

Answer (score 4):

```
char digit;
std::ifstream file("digits.txt");
std::vector<int> digits;
// if you want the ASCII value of the digit.
1- while(file >> digit) digits.push_back(digit);
// if you want the numeric value of the digit.
2- while(file >> digit) digits.push_back(digit - '0');
```